# Is this incorrect functionality encoding related?

Tags: android, encoding, textview

I've created an Android app and actually everything works fine.

I get the data from a server via websockets but before sending it to the client it is compressed with a `GZIPOutputStream` on the server like this:

```
public class GZip {

    public static ByteBuffer compress(String msg) {
        if(msg == null || msg.length() == 0)
            return null;            
        ByteBuffer bytes = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
            gzip.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            gzip.close();
            bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(obj.toByteArray());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

On the client side (the Android app) the `String msg` is decompressed by:

```
private static final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) {
        String msg = null;
        try {
            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
                string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, UTF8_CHARSET));
            }
            gis.close();
            is.close();

            msg = string.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

So, from my understanding this should not produce any problems when dealiing with not US-ASCII characters since everything is en- or decoded properly in UTF-8.

For instance consider the word `Eckstoß` which contains the special character `ß`. So here is an example of three `TextViews` in the Android app which both display the word `Eckstoß`

[image]

What I find really strange here, is the fact that all three versions of the word `Exkstoß` are en/decoded as described above. However, in one line it is incorrectly displayed.

However, it even becomes (IMHO) weireder. This is actually a listview and when (due to scrolling) the `TextView` disappears and reappears (by e.g. downscrolling again), then (sometimes) the characters are then correctly displayed.

What could cause this strange problem?

Comment: I have a feeling that you do not have any issues with content transfer maybe with the message you are generating or maybe with creating the UI. When you debug the message after decompression, is everything looking ok?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

You read the decompressed bytes in blocks of 32 bytes and then convert from bytes to utf8 characters with this snippet:

```
new String(data, 0, bytesRead, UTF8_CHARSET)
```

Could the problem be that the 32 bytes in `data` do not align with a character boundaries? I.e. the special characters are encoded with two or more bytes but not all bytes of the last character are in the `data` buffer.

This theory does not explain why scrolling would give you different results.

Answer (score 0):

When a unicode character is encoded in UTF-8, the number of resultant bytes is 1, 2, 3 or 4. For example, when a Japanese character [U+3042](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3042/index.htm) is encoded in UTF-8, the number of resultant bytes is 3 (0xE3, 0x81, 0x82). Another example is [U+20BB7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bb7/index.htm). This unicode character is converted into 4 bytes (0xF0, 0xA0, 0xAE, 0xB7) when it is encoded in UTF-8.

Suppose `gis.read(data)` is trying to read [0xF0, 0xA0, 0xAE, 0xB7] (= its unicode scalar value is U+20BB7). Is there any gurantee that `gis.read(data)` always returns 4? No. If it returns 2, for instance, `new String(data, 0, 2, UTF_8_CHARSET)` fails to parse the given byte array as a valid UTF-8 sequence.